# How to use Tinkerpops IndexableGraph - Features in a Neo4j - Graph?

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I am trying to get a vertex by using indexing-features, but only getting a NullPointerException.

Here are the relevant parts from my code:

```
Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
config.put( Config.NODE_KEYS_INDEXABLE, "type, categoryName" );
config.put( Config.NODE_AUTO_INDEXING, "true" );

GraphDatabaseService neoGraphDbService = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(dblocation,config);
Graph tiGraphDb = new Neo4jGraph(neoGraphDbService, false);

...
//This category is saved correctly
ICategory mashineCategory = manager.frame(tiGraphDb.addVertex(null),
            ICategory.class);

//this Property should be indexable...
mashineCategory.setCategoryName("mashineCategory");
mashineCategory.setType(NodeTypes.CATEGORY.toString());
...

//Here I´m getting a NullPointerException
String catName = "mashineCategory";
Vertex foundMashineCategory = ((IndexableGraph)tiGraphDb).getIndex(Index.VERTICES, Vertex.class).get("categoryName", catName).iterator().next();
```

when debugging i can see that the autoIndex from the rawGraph (Neo4j Graph) has its autoindex enabled, with its correct values. Looking at the Tinkerpop - Graph, the Index seems to be empty...

Comment: Mmh, when you instantiate the Neo4jGraph(gdb, false), Blueprints in the current implementation will leave all indexes alone, since it asumes you know what you are doing and have already what you need, so no default automatic indexes are created thereafter.

Comment: I see... what I want to do is using the the tinkerpop framework for indexing, the gremlin java api for some queries, and the "frames" - framewok for object mapping. But i still want to use Neoclipse for browsing the graph... when i instantiate my graph like new Neo4jGraph(gdb, [true]) the reference node will be messed up, and Neoclipse have problems to load the graph (related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938890/how-to-deal-with-the-neo4j-referencenode-when-using-tinkerpop)... is there a way to get this running? Are there some alternatives?

Comment: well, you could pull up neo4j server over your db, and raise an issue in https://github.com/neo4j/neoclipse/issues so we (or you) could fix the feature :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, there are some issues with caching existing indices from an existing neo4j-graph. I was using the actual stable version of 1.1 (core and neo4jgraph). So I guess it will be fixed in a further version.